# I would like to know if there are special terms for differnt types of inheritance

Tags: inheritance

Are there terms to distinguish these two different types of inheritance?
The one type of inheritance is

```
vehicle - car.
```

(these classes have some similarities).

But then there is for example

```
event - car
```

Of course there are also similarities (as in the above example), but here is more a special notion of "to enhance a class with a funtionality" rather than "two classes have similarities and now I create a class where I put the common attributes".

I use the last example in JavaScript to make the car class "eventable", so I can call "register_event" or "trigger_event" on car objects.

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that in your code, you have `car` class inheriting from `event` class? This looks wrong; composition (or similar construct, depending on what you're actually doing) should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second form of inheritance, `event` or `eventable` could be called a [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). A mixin provides a specialized behavior through inheritance, and possibly additional members in languages that support multiple inheritance of classes.